# USB 3.1 AC Coupling Capacitor Implementation

Tags: capacitor, usb, ac, coupling

How should the AC coupling should be implemented when connecting a [USB 3.1 hub](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb8041a.pdf) to a USB Type-C connector through a [MUX](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/hd3ss3220.pdf). Is it:

1. Both sides of each MUX.

[image: 1. Both sides of each MUX]

2. On the switched output of each MUX.

[image: 2. On the switched output of each MUX.]

3. On the input to each MUX.

[image: 3. On the input to each MUX.]

I think it should be option 2, however, the capacitors should be placed close to the SSTX pins of the hub.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is option 3. You can look at Ti's USB Type-C™ Mini Dock EVM for reference: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sllu248b/sllu248b.pdf

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. Okay, it looks like the AC coupling capacitors should be placed close to the connector, just after the common mode filter and ESD protection.